# Save HTML Tags into Mysql From TinyMCE for Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tinymce

currently, I success to create a page with php on codeigniter. now, I need to save my html content from tinymce into mysql and retrieve it again on homepage. I success to save it into database but fail to read it again from tinymce when I try to edit from admin page. I believe this is because convert html tag into special characters. but I don't know where is it... please help. thanks for your advance

UPDATE

Below is how I insert data from tinymce to mysql with php

```
            $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $fulltext = $this->input->post('create_post');
        $introtext = $this->input->post('create_intro');
        $meta_description = $this->input->post('meta_description');
        $meta_keywords = $this->input->post('meta_keywords');
        $media_intro = $this->input->post('media_intro');
        $media_full = $this->input->post('media_full');
        $status = false;
        $publish_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $modified_date = '';
        $data = array('title'=>$title,'introtext'=>$introtext,'fulltext'=>$fulltext,'meta_description'=>$meta_description,'meta_keywords'=>$meta_keywords,'media_intro'=>$media_intro,'media_full'=>$media_full,'status'=>$status,'publish_date'=>$publish_date,'modified_date'=>$modified_date);
        $insert = $this->db->insert('ibnusyuhadap3_content',$data);
```

and below is update for mysql

```
            $id = $this->input->post('postId');
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $fulltext = $this->input->post('create_post');
        $introtext = $this->input->post('create_intro');
        $meta_description = $this->input->post('meta_description');
        $meta_keywords = $this->input->post('meta_keywords');
        $media_intro = $this->input->post('media_intro');
        $media_full = $this->input->post('media_full');
        $status = false;
        $modified_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data = array('title'=>$title,'introtext'=>$introtext,'fulltext'=>$fulltext,'meta_description'=>$meta_description,'meta_keywords'=>$meta_keywords,'media_intro'=>$media_intro,'media_full'=>$media_full,'modified_date'=>$modified_date);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $update = $this->db->update('ibnusyuhadap3_content', $data);
```

and below is the code to get content what I want

```
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ibnusyuhadap3_content WHERE id=' . $postId);
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    $title = $row->title;
    $fulltext = $row->fulltext;
    $introtext = $row->introtext;
    $meta_description = $row->meta_description;
    $meta_keywords = $row->meta_keywords;
    $media_intro = $row->media_intro;
    $media_full = $row->media_full;
    $modified_date = $row->modified_date;
}
```

and below is jquery, I am using jquery to set content for tinymce from database

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var title = '<?php print_r($title);?>';
        var contentPost = '<?php print_r($fulltext);?>';
        var contentIntro = '<?php print_r($introtext);?>';
        var metaDes = '<?php print_r($meta_description);?>';
        var metaKey = '<?php print_r($meta_keywords);?>';
        var mediaIntro = '<?php print_r($media_intro);?>';
        var mediaFull = '<?php print_r($media_full);?>';
        var modifedDate = '<?php print_r($modified_date);?>';
        $('#inputName3').val(title);
        $('#create_post').html(contentPost);
        $('#create_intro').html(contentIntro);
        $('#inputName1').val(metaDes);
        $('#inputName0').val(metaKey);
        $('#inputName4').val(mediaIntro);
        $('#inputName5').val(mediaFull);
    });
```

Everything is ok when I create a content, but fail to reload it using tinymce, and if I access it directly using php to get mysql content, I can get all I need except $fulltext and $introtext. Because I design these for html tag.

Comment: Are you saving content in blob or text data type field?

Comment: @kumar_v I am using mediumtext in mysql.. is this problem?

Comment: add your action code.

Comment: @kumar_v : I updated to code like what you need to know.

Comment: why you are using `<?php print_r($title);?>`? you need to use <?php echo $title;?>